# Can I have protoc generate an array of int in Java?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

Using protocol buffers compiler version 2.6.0, a field declared as

```
repeated int32 values = 1;
```

generates in Java a field like:

```
private java.util.List<java.lang.Integer> values;
```

I would like to generate:

```
private int[] values;
```

along with compatible setters/getters. Is this possible out of the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't. You have to convert between array and list by yourself.

If it helps, take a look at Hadoop project. It has a lots of static methods to help the conversion between java object and proto object.
[PBHelperClient.java](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/branch-2.8/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs-client/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/protocolPB/PBHelperClient.java).  As you can see, there's a lots of conversion between array and list.

Comment: For now hadoop uses protobuf-2.5.0, but I don't see the difference with 2.6.0